# Java Generics: Member of Own Type

Tags: java, generics

The following example illustrates my problem (I want the mother of a `Lion` to be a `Lion`, the mother of a `Monkey` to be a `Monkey` and so on).

```
public class Animal<T extends Animal> {

    private T mother;

    public void setMother(T mother) {
        this.mother = mother;
    }

    public void receiveChild(T child) {
        child.setMother(this);
    }

}
```

The compiler gives me the following warning:

```
Animal.java:10: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to setMother(T) as a member
of the raw type Animal
                child.setMother(this);
                               ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Animal declared in class Animal
```

Is it possible to do this in a type safe way?

Comment: @Andreas, what?  `<T extends Animal<T>>` is meaningful and a trick used extensively throughout Java (most notably with enums).